# Float right based on wrong item

Tags: html, css

I have an array of items I want to list (listed from a database)

```
<ul class="allitems">
  <li class="item laying left">Item1</li>
  <li class="item laying left">Item2</li>
  <li class="item standing right">Item3</li>
  <li class="item standing left">Item4</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item5</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item6</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

All items are floated left, but the issue that Item3 is floated left relatively to Item2. I want to be on the "top" (as arrow illustrates) relativity to Item1.

**The css:**

```
.allitems {list-style-type: none;margin:0;padding:0;width:1000px;}
.allitems .item {margin-bottom:20px;}
.allitems .item.laying {width:660px;height:230px;background:#006505;color:#fff;float:left;}
.allitems .item.standing {width:320px;height:480px;background:#007cb2;color:#fff;float:left;}
.allitems .item.standing.left {margin-right:20px;}
.allitems .item.standing.right {margin-left:20px;}
```

How can I solve this without changing the order of the items? (with css!). I have no problem adding html, but I can't change the order.

Comment: Please add your CSS\

Comment: @LinkinTED - added the css

Comment: can you show the rest of your code, so we could find out what is the problem

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - no sorry I can't do this. The supplied code should be enough? What are you missing?

Comment: the CSS obviously, now you posted it.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - aha. I've posted it when it asked for by LinkinTed! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by not floating the `standing.right` element - just add margin to it instead:

```css
.allitems {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1000px;
}
.allitems .item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.allitems .item.laying {
  width: 660px;
  height: 230px;
  background: #006505;
  color: #fff;
}
.allitems .item.standing {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #007cb2;
  color: #fff;
}
.allitems .item.standing.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.allitems .item.standing.right {
  float: none;
  /*remove float and margin left auto instead*/
  margin-left: auto;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="allitems">
  <li class="item laying left">Item1</li>
  <li class="item laying left">Item2</li>
  <li class="item standing right">Item3</li>
  <li class="item standing left">Item4</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item5</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item6</li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

Just seen you don't want to use a specific pixel value on the margin, so instead of margin left `680px`, you can use `margin-left:auto` and this will just right align the standing div (see edited snippet above)

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative margin to `.standing.right`

```css
.allitems {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1000px;
}
.allitems .item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.allitems .item.laying {
  width: 660px;
  height: 230px;
  background: #006505;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}
.allitems .item.standing {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #007cb2;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}
.allitems .item.standing.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.allitems .item.standing.right {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -250px; /* added this line */
}
```

```html
<ul class="allitems">
  <li class="item laying left">Item1</li>
  <li class="item laying left">Item2</li>
  <li class="item standing right">Item3</li>
  <li class="item standing left">Item4</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item5</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Positioning the `item3` to `relative` & adding a negative `top` **OR** positive `bottom` value equal to the height of item1 + item2 seems to work. You need to only change the item3 class like this

```
.allitems .item.standing.right {
   margin-left:20px;
   position: relative;
   top: -15.5em; //or bottom: 15.5em/pc
}
```

Can you try this & let me know.

Comment: I don't want any css to relied to specific pixels. The pixels would change and that would be a mess trying to adapt to different smartphones etc.

Comment: So use `em` or `pc` instead. Equivalent is `top: -15.5em;` or `top: -15.5pc;` updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the order of your HTML elements: put **Item3** before **Item2**:

```
<ul class="allitems">
  <li class="item laying left">Item1</li>
  <li class="item standing right">Item3</li>
  <li class="item laying left">Item2</li>
  <li class="item standing left">Item4</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item5</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item6</li>
</ul>
```

Then, just add `float:right` to **Item3**.

Try with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ehL8fLs/) :)

Comment: I tried to be very clear that I can't change the order ot the items. So this would not work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

By using positioning and by changing class name of item3 to item2

```css
.allitems {list-style-type: none;margin:0;padding:0;width:1000px;}
.allitems .item {margin-bottom:20px;}
.allitems .item.laying {width:660px;height:230px;background:#006505;color:#fff;float:left;}
.allitems .item.layingleft {width:660px;height:230px;background:#006505;color:#fff;float:left;position: absolute;top: 258px;}
.allitems .item.standing {width:320px;height:480px;background:#007cb2;color:#fff;float:left;}
.allitems .item.standing.left {margin-right:20px;}
.allitems .item.standing.right {margin-left:20px;}
```

```html
<ul class="allitems">
  <li class="item laying">Item1</li>
  <li class="item standing right">Item2</li>
  <li class="item layingleft ">Item3</li>
  <li class="item standing left">Item4</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item5</li>
  <li class="item laying right">Item6</li>
 </ul>
```